# why css apply #flowerContainer img rule instead of applying #flower rule

Tags: css

OK there are a lot of articles talking about cascading priorities in CSS, I recently read [this one](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css) and there is some points i figured it out:-

1. id weight more than class and class more than tag
2. id weight the same as inline style but since inline comes later it wins the overriding rule
3. the more selector weight more than the less selector i.e. `.container img` rule will override `img` rules

Take a look at this code:-

```
<div id="flowerContainer" >
     <img id="flower" src="..." />
</div>
```

Try to apply the following rules:-

```
#flowerContainer img{width:500px;}
#flower {width:300px}
```

According to the second rule the `#flower` width rule should be applied but the `#flowerContainer img` is applied instead why ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) is the official documentation on how CSS calculates which selectors take precedence.

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of element names in the selector (= c) ignore    pseudo-elements.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large
>   base) gives the specificity.
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```
> *             {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
> LI            {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI         {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL+LI      {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> H1 + *[REL=up]{}  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red  {}  /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */ 
> LI.red.level  {}  /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
> #x34y         {}  /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> ```

`#id element` rules (101) are more specific than `#id` rules (100), so they will take precedence.

Comment: Don't think so.  ID rules (#) should take precedence over class (.) or element (img) rules.  However, ID + element (# img) might well be getting counted as more specific that just ID, even though the ID doesn't apply to the element

Comment: yes but this applies to the rules of the same weight i.e. internal and external stylesheet while id and inline style carry the same weight which is higher than internal and external stylesheets. logically the id refers to the element exclusively as there is no more than one id per element. in my example i select id followed by any child tag once, then i specify the id of the element itself once. i think that element id should win the race

Comment: @MostafaNagib - Then you need to clarify where the rules are located.  Your question indicates to me that they are located at the same level (in the same file), so standard precedence applies.  Location only affects results of equal weighting.

Comment: @RogerWillcocks yes you're right , notice that i add the 2 CSS code next to each other that format implicitly says they are at the same level :)

Answer (score 2):

The specificity of `#flowerContainer img` is higher than the specificity for `#flower`, which is why that rule was applied there.

This is because one of them only has an ID selector while the other has both an ID selector *and* a type selector.

Read more at the MDN about specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: and hence img#flower  should then take precedence over either of the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

First you should read how `CSS` calculate the specificity [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of element names in the selector (= c)
>     ignore pseudo-elements.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

So in the case of,

```
#flowerContainer img { width:500px; } /* a=1,b=0,c=1 (a-b-c = 101) */

#flower { width:300px; } /* a=1,b=0,c=0 (a-b-c = 100) */
```

So `#flowerContainer img` (101) is more specific than #flower (100)

Comment: Dude you should not copy my answer!